# Send int value to server from iOS device

Tags: ios, post

I have to POST int value to server. For what concern String value it's well explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23321570/insert-data-into-remote-mysql-database-by-post-method-from-ios-device) article, but with "int" i don't know how to set "setHTTPBody"

Answer (score 0):

`HTTPBody` accepts `NSData`. You have to convert the int to a NSString or put the integer inside a `NSDictionary` and convert the `NSString`/`NSDictionary` to `NSData` and set to `HTTPBody`. This all depends on the web service/URL you are trying to call. So first try to understand in which format your web service accepts the data.