# Sending HTTP POST request done but getting back answer?

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

I've managed to create a POST request to my server from my iOS application for creating a new user in my SQL database. But now, how do I handle it further?

In my `api.php` there are some `echo's` that say if something is done with succes like `echo 'User registered';`.

Do I need to check that string with the method from `NSURLConnectionDelegate` :

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)data{
    NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@", newStr);
}
```

Or how do I need to handle the answer from my `api.php`?

Kind regards

Comment: Did you implement `connection:didReceiveResponse`, `connection:didFailWithError`, `connection:didFinishLoading` ? If so, show us some code. Otherwise, can you show what `the api.php` looks like ?

This thread may help : http://stackoverflow.com/q/9501238/2791407

Comment: My api returns echo's on my webpage. So there is no need to post my `api.php`. It returns things like "User registered", "Email already exists" and stuff. The question is how do I handle these answers in my iOS app? Like with the example i've given to check my echo with a string in my iOS app or on an other way?

Comment: You can do it with a string, no problem with that way. Or you can use an enum if possible. To understand well, do your `NSLog(@"%@", newStr);`'s showing the good result or not ?

Comment: Yes it does. It just looks like a primitive way of doing it. I'm concern about security and stuff, maybe there was an other way handeling stuff like this.

Comment: You can encrypt your data for more security. There's many result if you google `NSURLConnectionDelegate encryption` : http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/use-https-certificate-handling-to-protect-your-ios-app/